# Building a crawler to input data into website search engine extract results

Tags: python, web-crawler, extract

I need to extract data from a website that requires an input in order to provide this data. I have a list of websites that I want to run through a search engine and extract the results that is provided.

My first question is, is this even possible? If so, how would I go about doing it?

The website I want to run my list of websites through is https://neilpatel.com. In order to extract the correct data, I need to input my list of websites, choose the correct language (e.g. danish) in the language drop-down menu and hit search. This sends me to a page, where I can see the estimated Organic Monthly Traffic of a particular website.

`Website           Organic Monthly Traffic`
`www.vvs.dk        1,079`
`www.dekra.dk      7,756`
`...               ...`

My wish is to automate this process, so that in a dream scenario, I can upload a list in Python, run the code and extract the estimated organic traffic of all websites on the list.

I have looked for help for 2 days. The only examples that came close to helping me were too old and all others were not approximate enough to my problem.

Thanks a bunch in advance.

Comment: You could look into using selenium to interact with the website.

Comment: web page use JavaScript so you may need [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control web browser which can run JavaScript